# Why parallel processing taking longer than usual code?

Tags: parallel-processing, nlp, python-multiprocessing, gensim, word2vec

The idea is to update a particular pre-trained word2vec model with different sets of new corpus. I have the following

```
# c1, c2 are each a list of 100 files
filelist = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10]

def update_model(files):
    # loading a pre-trained model
    trained_model = gensim.models.Word2Vec.load("model_both_100")
    # Document feeder is an iterable
    docs = DocumentFeeder(files)
    trained_model.build_vocab(docs, update=True)
    trained_model.train(docs, total_examples=trained_model.corpus_count, epochs=trained_model.epochs)

with Pool(processes=10) as P:
    P.map(update_model, filelist)
```

it takes about ~13 minutes to run. But the non-parallel version (looping over `filelist`) takes ~11 min. Why is this happening? Running on a 12 core cpu.

Answer (score 1):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` training already uses multiple threads – depending on the `workers` parameter at model creation. (The default is to use `workers=3`, but your model may have been initialized to use even more.)

So you are launching 10 (heavyweight) processes, each separately loading a full-size model. That could easily trigger heavy memory usage & thus virtual-memory swapping.

Then each of those models does its own (single-threaded) vocabulary-expansion, then its (one manager thread and 3 or more worker threads) training. If they're all in training simultaneously, than means 40 threads active, within 10 OS processes, on your 12 core processor. There's no reason to necessarily expect a speedup in such a situation, and the contention of more-threads-than-cores, and all contending for access to totally different loaded model memory ranges, could easily explain a slowdown.

Are you really trying to create 10 separate incrementally-updated models? (Do they get re-saved to 10 different filenames after the update-training?)

Comment: Yes. I am trying exactly that. I am going to save 10 separate incrementally-updated models (but just the keyvectors only). Actually I have to do that more than 1000 times and I am going to post a seperate question on how to optimize the space.

Comment: So, how can make the process faster? I am working on High Performance Compute cluster and have some budget for cloud too. Whats the best solution to parrellize/fasten up the process?

Comment: As a separate matter, such incremental training is fraught with difficult issues of balance & compatibility between the original model, and the incremental updates. I don't know your full setup & goals, but I suspect such tens (or thousand) alternate incremental-updates to the same base model are not providing the value you're hoping for.

Comment: For speed, attempting multi-process parallelism on the exact same machine would need to very-carefully consider the issues of swapping, memory-contention, and core-contention I mentioned. Depending on your full cluster resources, it might make the most sense to figure out what does a single model's update as fast as possible - parameters, worker-threads, etc – then repeat that on N completely-separate machines (where there's no contention).